# Trouble Importing a 3th party maven library from github to Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

So this is my first time doing this, i am trying to import this project  https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-java-api to my new clean intellij maven project.

i set my system variable MAVEN_HOME to:

- C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2\plugins\maven\lib

And then im trying to install the 3th party library to my local m2 repository.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\Users\Leroy\.m2\repository -DgroupId=com.binance.api - 
DartifactId=binance-api-client -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

cmd gives me the message that 'mvn is not recognized as an internal or external command'

What am i doing wrong here?

thank you in advance!

Comment: This has nothing to do with Maven or Java. When running executable in the CLI, that executable must be found in a directory that is part of the PATH environment variable.

Comment: You don't need to install this into your local repository. Just add it as a dependency to your pom.xml, and maven will fetch it from the central maven repository when you build your project. But you will need to correctly install maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not installed maven properly or it's not on PATH (refer this to properly install  [maven](https://maven.apache.org/install.html) )
Or Add the dependency along with external repo to **pom** file then choose `maven > Re-import` from **intelij** it should fix the import issues

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the problem, my mistake was that i assumed it was installed with Intellij as it by default provides the option to create a maven project.